# Using PPS pressure sensors in ROS

Tags: ros, sensor

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Recently we acquired touch sensor pads for our Barrett hands from PPS. I would like to use these sensors on linux and integrate them into ROS, but PPS offers no support in this direction. Yet I have seen that Joe Romano has used this system on the PR2, which I assume is linux based. I have checked out the repository and found the hardware_interface.h" which has declarations for some classes involving this sensor, but I can't seem to find any implementation. Does anyone have ideas/ resources I could use to tackle this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28430/using-pps-pressure-sensors-in-ros/) by [Woutervdh](https://answers.ros.org/users/1852/woutervdh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-02-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

On the PR2, we have the fingertip sensors connected by an SPI interface to our custom gripper control board, which communicates with the rest of the robot over EtherCAT. This may be overly complicated for your setup.

If you sensors have an SPI interface, you probably want to find or build an SPI to computer interface; an Arduino and rosserial is probably a good place to start.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2012-02-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1